# Swift - Obj-c linking stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

After cleaning a build folder my obj-c to swift linking stopped working.

Have this error in

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
File not found
```

And all classes which are marked @objc are not recognized anymore. What happened? I've cleaned a build folder many times before and facing the problem for the very first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: `MyProject-Swift.h` header is an auto-generated header which is recreated every time you successfully build your application.

Since you cleaned build folder you also don't have this header generated.

**Solution**: You need to successfully build your project once so that Xcode will generate `MyProject-Swift.h` again. 
For that comment out everything that gives you an error, until you can build it. And after that uncomment everything.

Comment: How do I build an App if dont have any other problems highlighted?

Comment: @s1ddok comment "#import "MyProject-Swift.h" first. Than everything else that gives you errors, if there is anything.

Comment: well, if comment it, I couldnt use my @objc classes and app wont launch without them

Comment: @s1ddok and that's why you need to comment out every call to your objc API. That's the whole point.

Comment: @s1ddok comment it out without hesitations, you just need to build it once, after that you will uncomment everything and it will work.

Comment: well, thanks, I didnt comment it, but somehow fixed the problem!

Comment: @s1ddok could you please give more details on "somehow". It might be useful for other users.

Comment: apparently I broke everything with custom shell script, because I'm dead newbie in it, I deleted it from build phases and project did compile.

Comment: If cleaning requires that you comment out a bunch of code, rebuild, comment the code back in, then rebuild again, I consider that a pretty big screwup on Apple's part.